# Drunkard's breath

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there any word, or short expression, to describe the stale-ish, alcoholic smell coming from someone who drank too much - particularly in the breath?

I'm looking for something more descriptive, and maybe visceral, than "drunken" in a line like "she avoided his drunken kiss".

Some further alternative including smelling like smoking-and-garlic-and-old-beer, for example, would be interesting too :).

Comment: She avoided his debauched and drink-sodden kisses!

Comment: Mhm... not quite, but you made me think that "drenched" can be a good beginning...

Comment: *"...his breath reeked of alcohol"* is your usual bog-standard phrase. Are you looking for that, or for something more creative?

Comment: She avoided his putrid kisses.

Comment: Used with “kiss” these could possibly mean something much more pleasant, but with “breath” they might work: “100-proof breath”/”intoxicating breath.”  But to get the added notion of “staleness” (or at least that of ‘smokiness’)  you’d have to add something like “she avoided his 100-proof, pack-a-day kiss/breath.”

Comment: If it's already understood that the guy is drunk, "ketone kiss" might work--it's sharper than, say "boozey bussing", so there's a potential perspective (narrative point of view) issue. Alternatively, maybe "acetone amors".

Comment: Thanks all, though still nothing comes close to what I expected. I was hoping for something Douglas-Adams-like; I'd swear I read something in his style which, as was typical for him, used rather unassuming words to strike you in that unique angle needed to snap you into context. (Maybe it was Terry Pratchett...?)

Comment: There are a billion synonyms for "under the influence of alcohol". I suggest you consult a thesaurus and find the option that sounds best to you. https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/boozy

Comment: Brewery breath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me offer ["booze breath"](http://www.wikihow.com/Cure-Alcohol-Breath). Same thing as "alcohol breath", but has a nice ring to it due to alliteration.

Answer (score 1):

> **Miasma**
> noun
> [countable, usually singular, uncountable]   (literary)
> ​a mass of air that is dirty and smells unpleasant
>
> A miasma of stale alcohol hung around him.

[[Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/miasma)]

PS: This is a word I heard yesterday on a TV interview. I came across your post while searching for this word.

Comment: It's an unusual usage (Google have many duplicate hits). Usually confined to marshes (and fairly rare then too).

Answer (score 0):

Rank or rotten? "His rank/rotten breath repulsed her."

Or, "The sour bloom of decay wafted from his amorous maw." :-P

Answer (score -1):

I've always enjoyed "crapulous", though it refers more to the state of being hung over than drunken.

Comment: Not the intended meaning, and too... rare?